data set and loader issues, stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [72, 4] at entry 0 and [68, 4] at entry 56
I've been trying to make this simple lstm code works but it's really confusing for me the data loader, I have implemented multiple versions, and yet the window of 72 and forecast of 12 is not working for the data loader. can you tell me what is wrong?
Dataset
class TimeSeriesDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, input_seq_length=72, output_seq_length=12, train=True):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)  # Load CSV file
        self.input_seq_length = input_seq_length
        self.output_seq_length = output_seq_length
        self.train = train
        
        # Normalize data
        self.scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        self.data[['column4']] = self.scaler.fit_transform(self.data[['column4']])
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data) - self.input_seq_length - self.output_seq_length + 1  # Adjusted length to exclude incomplete sequences
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if self.train:
            idx += np.random.randint(0, self.input_seq_length)  # Randomize training data
        input_data = self.data.iloc[idx:idx+self.input_seq_length].values
        target = self.data.iloc[idx+self.input_seq_length:idx+self.input_seq_length+self.output_seq_length]['column4'].values
        
        # Pad sequences
        input_data = [torch.tensor(sequence, dtype=torch.float) for sequence in input_data]
        input_data = pad_sequence(input_data, batch_first=True)
        
        return input_data, torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.float)


for reproducibility
LSTM

# Define LSTM model
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers=1):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out

traing loop

# Define training function
def train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=100):
    train_losses = []
    val_losses = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0.0
        for inputs, targets in train_loader:
            print(epoch, inputs.shape, targets.shape)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss += loss.item()
        train_losses.append(train_loss / len(train_loader))
        
        model.eval()
        val_loss = 0.0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for inputs, targets in val_loader:
                outputs = model(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
                val_loss += loss.item()
            val_losses.append(val_loss / len(val_loader))
        
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Train Loss: {train_losses[-1]}, Val Loss: {val_losses[-1]}')
    
    return train_losses, val_losses

# Define function to plot losses
def plot_losses(train_losses, val_losses):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(range(len(train_losses))), y=train_losses, mode='lines', name='Train Loss'))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(range(len(val_losses))), y=val_losses, mode='lines', name='Val Loss'))
    fig.update_layout(title='Training and Validation Losses', xaxis_title='Epoch', yaxis_title='Loss')
    fig.show()

main

# Main function
def main():
    # Load data
    dataset = TimeSeriesDataset('sample_data.csv')
    
    # Split data into train, validation, and test sets
    train_size = int(0.6 * len(dataset))
    val_size = int(0.2 * len(dataset))
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size - val_size
    train_data, val_data, test_data = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size, test_size])
    
    # Create data loaders
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=64)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=64)
    
    # Initialize model, loss function, and optimizer
    model = LSTMModel(input_size=dataset.data.shape[1], hidden_size=64, output_size=1)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    
    # Train model
    train_losses, val_losses = train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer)
    
    # Plot losses
    plot_losses(train_losses, val_losses)
    
    # Evaluate model on test data
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, targets in test_loader:
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
            test_loss += loss.item()
    print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss / len(test_loader)}')

# Run main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


generate sample data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Generate sample data
num_rows = 1200
start_date = datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1)
time_index = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5*i) for i in range(num_rows)]
column1 = np.random.randn(num_rows) * 10  # Sample values for column 1
column2 = np.random.randn(num_rows) * 100  # Sample values for column 2
column3 = np.random.randn(num_rows) * 1000  # Sample values for column 3
column4 = np.random.randn(num_rows) * 10000  # Sample values for column 4

# Create DataFrame
data = {
    # 'datetime': time_index,
    'column1': column1.astype(float),
    'column2': column2.astype(float),
    'column3': column3.astype(float),
    'column4': column4.astype(float)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save to CSV
df.to_csv('sample_data.csv', index=False)



This issue was the randomize exceeded the data len itself
if self.train:
            idx += np.random.randint(0, self.input_seq_length)  # Randomize training data

it was removed OR update the get item
def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data) - self.input_seq_length - self.output_seq_length - 72 + 1  # Adjusted length to exclude incomplete sequences


